# Cursor loop infinite loop by using inser into

Tags: sql-server-2008, cursor, infinite-loop, insertion

I want to use a cursor for inserting data.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[VehBlocMajStatut] 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@NO_Veh int,
@Statut int

AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @Temp_appel int
DECLARE appel_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT NO_APPEL FROM ESPMEDS_LS_APPVEH WHERE NO_VEHICULE = @NO_Veh

OPEN appel_cursor;

FETCH NEXT FROM appel_cursor INTO @Temp_appel;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO ESPMEDS_LS_APPVEH (NO_VEHICULE, NO_APPEL, STATUT, DATEVEH)
    VALUES (@NO_Veh, @Temp_appel, @Statut, GETDATE())

    FETCH NEXT FROM appel_cursor INTO @Temp_appel;


END
close appel_cursor
deallocate appel_cursor
END
```

Unfortunately it turns into an infinite loop.  When I commented the `INSERT INTO` clause then it works normally.

How can I do an insert with a cursor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No cursor is needed.

```
INSERT INTO ESPMEDS_LS_APPVEH 
    (NO_VEHICULE, NO_APPEL, STATUT, DATEVEH)
    SELECT @NO_Veh, NO_APPEL, @Statut, GETDATE()
        FROM ESPMEDS_LS_APPVEH 
        WHERE NO_VEHICULE = @NO_Veh
```

Comment: But just for curiosity why with cursor not work ? Is Cursor cannot be use with insert, coz i use with Update and i have no probleme. Or inside the loop i call another strore procedure that do the Insert ?

Comment: @user609511: 1) Since this answer solved your problem, please accept it by clicking on the check mark next to it. 2) Because you did not declare your cursor as `STATIC`, the inserts you performed within the loop were adding to the result set of the cursor, hence the infinite loop.